# Something like strings.xml in android in html

Tags: php, android, html

I'm searching for something that would allow me to have same html/php file for multiple languages like strings.xml does it in android.

Is that possible?

Comment: use `json` for various languages

Comment: HTML can use different languages, and add the other languages as a alternate tag I think

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of these jQuery plugin may help:

https://github.com/coderifous/jquery-localize

https://github.com/jquery/globalize